# How can I minimize the loss of quality when sending a photo to firebase?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have implemented sending a photo to firestore as a bitmap translated into a string, but the quality of the photo leaves much to be desired, how can I fix it?

```
val pickImage: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
) {
    if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (it.data != null) {
            val imageUri: Uri? = it.data !!!
            try {
                val inputStream: InputStream? = imageUri?.let { it1 ->
                    APP_ACTIVITY.contentResolver.openInputStream(
                        it1
                    )
                }

                val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
                options.inDither = false
                options.inScaled = false
                options.inPremultiplied = false
                options.inSampleSize = 1
                options.inPreferQualityOverSpeed = true
                val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream,null,options)
                var user_id = preferenceManager.getString(KEY_USER_ID)!
                mViewModel.sendMessageAsImage(bitmap!!,receiverUser.uid,user_id){
                    mBinding.typeMessageField.setText(null)
                }
            } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This code takes an image and translates it into a bitmap

```
private fun encodedImage(bitmap: Bitmap): String? {
    val previewWidth = 500
    val previewHeight = bitmap.height * previewWidth / bitmap.width
    val previewBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, previewWidth, previewHeight, false)
    val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    previewBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)
    val bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
    return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT)
}
```

I use this function to translate the bitmap into a string to write that value to a field in the firestore

```
 private fun getBitmapFromEncodedString(encodedImage:String): Bitmap {
         val bytes = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT)
         return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.size)
     }
```

With this code, I translate the string back into a bitmap to install in the ImageView

Comment: `This code takes an image and translates it into a bitmap` No. It takes a bitmap. Resizes the bitmap. (This gives you bad quality with resolution of 500 pixels only), makes a jpg from it and encodes the jpg base64.

Comment: You have a nice uri from an image file. Just send the bytes of the file to the database. No need to use an intermediate bitmap.

Comment: @blackapps I use uri now, but when I reopen the chat where the photos are displayed I get this error `opening provider com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.impl.MediaContentProvider from ProcessRecord{1dda6e6 23141:com.mimoza_app.notes.camphussop/u0a148} (pid=23141, uid=10148) which is not exported from UID 10126`

Comment: It does not make much sense to just post error mesages i think.